# Sensors(1) prints only GPU temperature

Tags: hardware, temperature

That's output of `sensors`

```
$ sensors
nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +110.0°C)
```

I'm worried if this is really GPU temperature?
How to obtain CPU temperature?
Are there coolers providing such info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not yet run `sudo sensors-detect` then you will need to do that. You'll also want to have it modify the `modules.conf` at the end if it detected new kernel modules that need to be loaded, so that they will be reloaded on reboots. After that, `sensors` should report more information. If not, it's possible the sensors in your system are unsupported, or there are none available.